# SimpleJdbcCall always omits the first parameter in function calls

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to use the `SimpleJdbcCall` class to call functions in an Oracle package, but every call ignores the first input parameter.
My code looks like this:

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate())
                .withSchemaName("MY_SCHEMA")
                .withCatalogName("MY_PACKAGE")
                .withFunctionName("MY_FUNCTION")
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("FIRST_ARGUMENT", Types.VARCHAR), new SqlParameter("SECOND_ARGUMENT", Types.VARCHAR));
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("FIRST_ARGUMENT", "VALUE1").addValue("SECOND_ARGUMENT", "VALUE2");
Integer result = call.executeFunction(Integer.class, params);
```

with my function being:

```
FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION(FIRST_ARGUMENTvarchar2, SECOND_ARGUMENTvarchar2) RETURN number;
```

The stacktrace shows this kind of errors:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{? = call MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE.MY_FUNCTION(?)}];
```

A parameter has been removed. A call to another function with just one parameter throws a similar error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{? = call MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE.MY_OTHER_FUNCTION()}];
```

I've tried debugging the Spring code, `spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.0.1.RELEASE` (`2.0.0` too), and I've come accross this code in the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext` class, when composing the call:

```
if (isFunction() || isReturnValueRequired()) {
            callString = "{? = call " +
                    (StringUtils.hasLength(catalogNameToUse) ? catalogNameToUse + "." : "") +
                    (StringUtils.hasLength(schemaNameToUse) ? schemaNameToUse + "." : "") +
                    procedureNameToUse + "(";
            parameterCount = -1;
        }
        else {
            callString = "{call " +
                    (StringUtils.hasLength(catalogNameToUse) ? catalogNameToUse + "." : "") +
                    (StringUtils.hasLength(schemaNameToUse) ? schemaNameToUse + "." : "") +
                    procedureNameToUse + "(";
        }

        for (SqlParameter parameter : this.callParameters) {
            if (!(parameter.isResultsParameter())) {
                if (parameterCount > 0) {
                    callString += ", ";
                }
                if (parameterCount >= 0) {
                    callString += createParameterBinding(parameter);
                }
                parameterCount++;
            }
        }
        callString += ")}";
```

If I've understood the code, the first parameter will **always** be ommited, am I right?
Has anybody had success in this situation?

---

M. Deinum is right and the return parameter must be specified too, I expected Spring to automatically add it when working with functions.
My code now:

```
    SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate())
                        .withSchemaName("MY_SCHEMA")
                        .withCatalogName("MY_PACKAGE")
                        .withFunctionName("MY_FUNCTION")
                        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                        .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("return",Types.INTEGER) 
                                            ,new SqlParameter("FIRST_ARGUMENT", Types.VARCHAR) 
                                            ,new SqlParameter("SECOND_ARGUMENT", Types.VARCHAR));
        SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("FIRST_ARGUMENT", "VALUE1").addValue("SECOND_ARGUMENT", "VALUE2");
        Integer result = call.executeFunction(Integer.class, params);
```

Comment: It is a function and a function should return something, the first argument is considered being the return value. If it isn't a function but a procedure then use `withProcedureName` instead of `withFunctionName`.